# XPATH count number of nodes with a not given attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

So I wanted to count how many videos every creator had for all the creators. Anybody can help me out?

`<Video videoID="v0006" link="" creatorID="u0001" imageLink=""/>`

I repeat this declaration multiple times with diferent creatorID.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using XPath-3.0 or above with a `for` expression and the `distinct-values(...)` function:

```
for $i in distinct-values(for $k in Video/@creatorID return $k) return concat('ID=',$i,', Count=',count(Video[@creatorID = $i]))
```

This expression creates strings in the format `ID=xxxx, Count=y`.
For example, if you put this in an XSLT-3.0 `xsl:value-of`, you can output all of the result delimited by a NEWLINE character this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in distinct-values(for $k in Video/@creatorID return $k) return concat('ID=',$i,', Count=',count(Video[@creatorID = $i]))" separator="&#xa;" />
```

For an example XML file like

```
<Video videoID="v0006" link="" creatorID="u0001" imageLink=""/>
<Video videoID="v0007" link="" creatorID="u0001" imageLink=""/>
<Video videoID="v0001" link="" creatorID="u0002" imageLink=""/>
<Video videoID="v0008" link="" creatorID="u0001" imageLink=""/>
<Video videoID="v0002" link="" creatorID="u0002" imageLink=""/>
```

its output would be

```
ID=u0001, Count=3
ID=u0002, Count=2
```

If you want to restrict the output to the IDs which have a certain minimum of occurrences, use an IF-THEN-ELSE (Here with a LET for better performance)

```
for $i in distinct-values(for $k in Video/@creatorID return $k) return let $c := count(Video[@creatorID = $i]), $s := concat('ID=',$i,', Count=',$c) return if ($c>2) then $s else ''
```

Output:

```
ID=u0001, Count=3
```

Comment: Is there any way to get just the ID of those who have X or more videos?